# shared service variables are undefined

Tags: angular

I have a shared service and it is always returning undefined. in App.component the value is retrieved successfully from thee html page, however, welcome component lose the value.

cshtml

```
<pm-app gwLinkID="111"></pm-app>
```

shared service

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class AppParamasService {
    constructor() {

    }
    private _ntName = new Subject<any>();
    ntNameValue = this._ntName.asObservable();

    private _gwLinkID = new Subject<any>();
    gwLinkIDValue = this._gwLinkID.asObservable();

    gwLinkIDReceived(gwLinkID: number) {
        this._gwLinkID.next(gwLinkID);
    }


}
```

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppParamasService } from './shared/app-params.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template:'<home></home>'


})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() gwLinkID: number;
    @Input() psnlUID: string;
    @Input() ntName: string;
    //pageTitle: any[];

    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(elm: ElementRef, private _param: AppParamasService) {
        this.gwLinkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID'); //value is coming
        this._param.gwLinkIDReceived (elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID'));



    }


    ngOnInit(): void {



    }

}
```

welcome.component this.gwLinkID is undefined

```
import { Component, ElementRef,Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'welcome.component.html'

})
export class WelcomeComponent {
    gwLinkID: number;
    constructor(elm: ElementRef,private _appParams: AppParamasService) {


        this._appParams.gwLinkIDValue.subscribe(gwLinkIDVal => {
            this.gwLinkID = gwLinkIDVal;
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Add console.log() traces to both constructors and to the gwLinkIDReceived method (or use your debugger), and you'll understand when each f them is called, and why you never receive the event. Why don't you use an input to pass data from the app to the home component? That's what they're for.

Comment: already done that :) app.component constructor is called first then welcome.component constructor gets called. Yes, input will work but not for my code, it works for some scenario for others I just need to get it from the shared service.

Comment: I tried to use input for this page and it did not work as well , null values

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/noIxTdhuD9DHBC3t98ls?p=preview

Comment: interesting , i still get undefined. there must be something wrong with my code.

Comment: got the input, however, i really need to get it from shared service

Comment: Well, just store it in the service, as is, rather than emitting it from a subject. Or store it in a BeahaviorSbject. The constructor of app is called before the constructor of home, so the event is emitted before the home subscribes.

Comment: thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed